# How i can get two span's text field from one div using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have html like this:

```html
<div class="event__scores fontBold">
    <span>1</span>
    &nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <span>2</span>
</div>
```

I find this element as follows:

```py
current_score = match.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "event__scores")]')
print(current_score.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

I can not understand what I need to do to get the text like `1 - 2` without using bs4 or something like that.
I know i can use bs4 like this:

```py
spans = soup.find_all('span')
result = ' - '.join([e.get_text() for e in spans])
```

But i want to know can i get similar result only using Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of `find` as it might be the case the element won't be loaded yet by the time you will be attempting to find it. Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more details

   ```
   current_score = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '//div[contains(@class, "event__scores")]')))
   ```
2. You're looking for a wrong property, you should be using [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), not `innerHTML`

   ```
   print(current_score.get_attribute('innerText'))
   ```

   or simply retrieve [WebElement.text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) property

   ```
   print(current_score.text)
   ```